# Google photo sphere

Tags: image-processing, texture-mapping

Does anyone have information on how to map the texture-image of a Google photo-sphere image onto a sphere yourself (not using the google api)? My goal is todo it myself in matlab but I was unable to find any information about the mapping coordinates.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find details about the metadata of a Photo Sphere here:
https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/metadata/

Essentially, the image uses equirectangular projection [1] which you only need to map on the inside of a sphere, and put the camera at the center.If the Photo Sphere is a full 360/180 degree panorama, then you can map the whole of the inside of a sphere. If it is only a partial panorama, then you can use the metadata inside the photo to determine the exact position you need to place the texture.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [warp function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/warp.html)?

```
a = imread('PANO.jpg');
[x,y,z] = sphere(200);
warp(x,y,z,a);
```

Using camera tools, you may set the camera position inside the sphere, but I think outside view can be enough with an adequate level of zoom.